# Sigmoid-Normal Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, normal-distribution

I conjecture that for any $\beta>0$,
\begin{align}
\sigma(\beta) > \Phi(x_{\beta})
\quad\text{where}\quad
x_{\beta} = \beta \phi(x_{\beta}).
\end{align}

- $\sigma$ denotes the sigmoid function defined by $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$.
- $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denote the standard normal cdf and pdf, respectively.

The conjecture seems to be true according to my numerical analysis, but I am unsure about a formal proof.

I would appreciate it if you would share your thoughts or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: $x_{\beta} = \beta \phi(x_{\beta})$ looks like a circular definition

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The definition is not circular, however. The equation $x = \beta \phi(x)$ has a unique solution, $x_{\beta} > 0$ for all $\beta > 0$.

Comment: It is true for $\beta >0$.  

From your $x_{\beta} = \beta \phi(x_{\beta})$, consider $b(x)=\frac{x}{\phi(x)}$ which is a bijection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which preserves signs so has an inverse.  You can say $\beta=b(x_\beta)$, i.e. $x_\beta=b^{-1}(\beta)$.  

Your assertion becomes that for any $x_\beta>0$ you have $\dfrac{1}{1+e^{-x_\beta/\phi(x_\beta)}} >\Phi(x_\beta)$, which is true - to prove it you might want to separate into small and large $x_\beta$ and find simple functions between the LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We rephrase the problem as follows.

**Problem.** Prove that, for all $\beta > 0$,
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{u} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t$$
where $u$ is a real number satisfying
$$u = \beta \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-u^2/2}.$$
(*Note*: Clearly, such $u$ exists (unique) and is positive.)

$\phantom{2}$

**Proof.**

We split into two cases.

**Case 1.** $\beta \ge 3$

Let $f(u) := u - \beta \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-u^2/2}$.
We have $f'(u) > 0$. We have $$f(\sqrt{2\ln \beta})
= \sqrt{2\ln \beta} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \ge \sqrt{2\ln 3} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} > 0 = f(u)$$ which results in $\sqrt{2\ln \beta} \ge u$.
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2\ln \beta}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t. \tag{1}$$

We have, for all $u>0$
$$1 - \frac{u^2 - 1}{u^3\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\mathrm{e}^{-u^2/2}\ge \int_{-\infty}^{u} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t. \tag{2}$$
(*Proof*: Let $g(u) := \mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS}$. We have
$g'(u) = - \frac{3}{u^4\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-u^2/2}< 0$ for all $u > 0$. Also, $g(\infty) = 0$. Thus, $g(u)\ge 0$ for all $u > 0$.)

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
> 1 - \frac{2\ln \beta - 1}{\sqrt{2\ln \beta}^3\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta}. \tag{3}$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathrm{e}^{-\beta} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^3\mathrm{e}^{\beta-3}}
 \le \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^3[1 + (\beta - 3) + \frac12(\beta - 3)^2]}, \tag{4}\\[6pt]
 &\frac{2\ln \beta - 1}{\sqrt{2\ln \beta}^3\sqrt{2\pi}} = \frac{1 - 1/(2\ln\beta)}{\sqrt{2\ln \beta}\sqrt{2\pi}} \ge \frac{1 - 1/(2\ln 3)}{\sqrt{2\ln \beta}\sqrt{2\pi}},\tag{5}\\[6pt]
 &\ln \beta = \ln 3 + \ln (1 + (\beta - 3)/3) \le \ln 3 + (\beta - 3)/3. \tag{6}
\end{align*}

From (3)-(6), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^3[1 + (\beta - 3) + \frac12(\beta - 3)^2]}}
> 1 - \frac{1 - 1/(2\ln 3)}{\sqrt{2\ln 3 + 2(\beta - 3)/3}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta},$$
or
$$\frac{1 - 1/(2\ln 3)}{\sqrt{2\ln 3 + 2(\beta - 3)/3}\cdot \sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta} > \frac{2}{\mathrm{e}^3(\beta^2 - 4\beta + 5) + 2},$$
or
$$\frac{(1 - 1/(2\ln 3))^2}{[2\ln 3 + 2(\beta - 3)/3]\cdot 2\pi}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta^2} > \frac{4}{[\mathrm{e}^3(\beta^2 - 4\beta + 5) + 2]^2},$$
or (using $\mathrm{e}^3 > 20$ and $2\ln 3 > 2 + 1/6$ and $2\ln 3 < 2 + 1/5$ and $2\pi < 6 + 1/3$)
$$\frac{(1 - 1/(2 + 1/6))^2}{[(2 + 1/5) + 2(\beta - 3)/3]\cdot (6 + 1/3)}\cdot \frac{1}{\beta^2} > \frac{4}{[20(\beta^2 - 4\beta + 5) + 2]^2},$$
or
$${\frac {1}{3211}}\,{\frac {220500\,{\beta}^{4}-1796110\,{\beta}^{3}+5767467\,{
   \beta}^{2}-8996400\,\beta+5735205}{ \left( 3+10\,\beta \right) {\beta}^{2} \left( 10\,
  {\beta}^{2}-40\,\beta+51 \right) ^{2}}}
> 0$$
which is true.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case 2.** $0 < \beta < 3$

Let $f(u) := u - \beta \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-u^2/2}$.
We have $f'(u) > 0$. Using $\sqrt{2\pi} > 5/2$ and $\mathrm{e}^{-2\beta^2/25} = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{2\beta^2/25}} \le \frac{1}{1+ 2\beta^2/25}$, we have
$$f(2\beta/5)
= \frac{2\beta}{5} -  \frac{\beta \mathrm{e}^{-2\beta^2/25}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \ge \frac{2\beta}{5} - \frac{ \beta \cdot \frac{2}{5}}{1+ 2\beta^2/25} = \frac{4\beta^3}{10\beta^2 + 125} > 0 = f(u)$$ which results in $2\beta/5 \ge u$.
It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
> \int_{-\infty}^{2\beta/5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t. \tag{7}$$

(i) If $11/4 \le \beta < 3$, we have
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
- \int_{-\infty}^{2\beta/5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t
\ge \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-11/4}}
- \int_{-\infty}^{2\cdot 3/5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t > 0.
$$

(ii) If $0 < \beta < 11/4$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
> \frac{2\beta}{5\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac12 > \int_{-\infty}^{2\beta/5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t. \tag{8}$$

Let $F(\beta) := \frac{1}{1 + \mathrm{e}^{-\beta}}
- \frac{2\beta}{5\sqrt{2\pi}} - \frac12$.
We have $F''(\beta) := - \frac{\mathrm{e}^\beta(\mathrm{e}^\beta - 1)}{(1 + \mathrm{e}^\beta)^3} > 0$.
Also, $F(0) = 0$ and $F(11/4) > 0 $.
Thus, $F(\beta) > 0$ on $(0, 11/4)$.

Let $G(\beta) := \frac{2\beta}{5\sqrt{2\pi}} + \frac12 - \int_{-\infty}^{2\beta/5} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-t^2/2}\, \mathrm{d} t$. We have $G'(\beta) = \frac{2(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-2\beta^2/25})}{5\sqrt{2\pi}} > 0$. Also, $G(0) = 0$. Thus, $G(\beta) > 0$ on $(0, 11/4)$.

Thus, (8) is true.

We are done.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is perfect. May I ask (from my curiosity) how you came up with the series of ingenious inequalities?

Comment: @Pierre For example, LHS of (2) is a result from the asymptotic expansion of the RHS of (2). (8) is to find a linear segment separating the two curves. We can do it with the help of Maple - a computer algebra system.